# PowerShell script not working with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I cannot manage to run the following PowerShell script remotely with `Invoke-Command`.

`Invoke-Command` from server:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {
    Param($env:FileLocation, $file)
    & "$env:FileLocation\$file"
} -ArgumentList ($env:FileLocation, $file) > ./windowsResult.txt
```

Remote script:

```
$Process = Start-Process "$env:DATABASE_HOME\bin\psql.exe" -ArgumentList "-p "5433" -U "postgres" -d "TESTDB" -f $env:LOC_SCRIPT\DBTestScript.2.sql" -Wait -PassThru

if ($Process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Success!!!!"
} else {
    Write-Host "Error while executing DB Scripts"
}
```

When executing this remote script it works and the database is getting updated successfully.

But when calling it with `Invoke-Command` it does not.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Don't use the `env:` qualifier for your parameters: `{param($FileLocation,$file) & "$FileLocation\$file"}`

Comment: we need to use env since, we don't know the location of the script which is being placed in the remote machine. We are reading the location of script using the ENVIRONMENT Variable.

Comment: Yes, on the client side (you should still pass `$env:FileLocation` to `ArgumentList`), but inside the remote scriptblock you can define the parameter variable names yourself.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen We are doing it for multiple machines, hence we can't hard-code the value, we need to use the environment variable to read the location

Comment: If you want to read it from the remote environment then don't pass it in as an argument

Comment: What does not work? What errors are you getting? Have you verified that the environment variables are available in your remote session (test with invoke or enter-pssession using the same credentials)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inject your script inside a block and execute it remotely?

```
$block={

    $Process = Start-Process "$env:DATABASE_HOME\bin\psql.exe" -ArgumentList "-p "5433" -U "postgres" -d "TESTDB" -f $env:LOC_SCRIPT\DBTestScript.2.sql" -Wait -PassThru

    if ($Process.ExitCode -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Success!!!!"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Error while executing DB Scripts"
    }
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $block
```

If you need the block to accept parameters, follow your syntax but don't use the `$env:` prefix

I hope I understood correctly what you need to achieve.